# SQL: Where Clause Match Fullname with First & LastName

Tags: sql-server, match, where-clause

I have two tables, which I need to match on

```
"Fullname"
```

against

```
 "FirstName" & "LastName"
```

and extract the userID from the **"FirstName"/"LastName"** table.
If there's a match retrieve the UserID if not Just Null

Example:
Table1 (With fullname)

```
|Sam Smith|
```

Must match with
Table2 (with first and last name)

```
| Sam | Smith |
```

And I would like to take into account if a person has three names.
(Fullname)

```
 |Sam Samual Smith|
```

vs. (First & Last Name)

```
|Sam Samual | Smith |
```

Any help needed, not sure how  to go around it,

Comment: Isn't this as simple as `WHERE t1.Fullname = t2.Firstname + ' ' + t2.Lastname` ? (probably not going to execute very well with indices though)

Answer (score 1):

As [Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen) suggested,

```
  SELECT *
  FROM [MainTable] M
  INNER JOIN [SubTable] S
  ON M.Fullname=S.Firstname + ' ' + S.Lastname; -- check if fullname is a of combination 
                                                -- firstname and lastname from other table
```

Replace the table names with your table names and put the fields you want in the select query as selecting all the fields could compromise the perfomance.

Comment: Thanks, that works nicely.  However I still have the issure regarding when I have names such as: | Martin Christian | Smith | (Firstname and LastName)  and the persons fullname in the other table  is | Martin Smith | and since I do not have the "Christian" in the fullname I won't receive any match.

Comment: That's going to make the query really slow because now you end up having to do a `LIKE` on both fields. I would suggest you do this complex matching *once* and store the results.

Comment: Also, you didn't mention that you would have to do this kind of comparison in your question. Please post complete questions. You mention having to deal with middle names at the bottom but then give an example where both tables contain the middle name. Your new issue is different. Please update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.FullName = T2.FirstName + ' ' + T2.LastName
```